# Cannot read List Type automatically from Firestore Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Whenever i tried to create a stream or just get the data from firestore and map it into object, the List field type always considered as dynamic

```
class Order{
  String itemId;
  String itemName;
  List<String> itemImage;
  Order({this.itemId, this.itemName, this.itemImage});

  factory Order.fromMap(Map<String , dynamic> parsedData){

    return Order(
      itemId: parsedData['itemId'],
      itemName: parsedData['itemName'],
      itemImage: parsedData['listImage'],
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the code to call the stream

```
Stream<List<Order>> getOrder(int unit) {
    return _firestore
        .collection(orderPath)
        .where("unit", whereIn: [unit])
        .snapshots()
        .map((QuerySnapshot snapshot) => snapshot.docs
            .map((DocumentSnapshot e) => Order.fromMap(e.data()))
            .toList());
  }
```

and when i use the stream Error always happened

```
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' of 'function result'
```

and would only work when i do changed the factory method fromMap like this

```
factory Order.fromMap(Map<String , dynamic> parsedData){
List<String> imageList = parsedData['itemImage'].map<String>((e) {
      String image = e;
      return image;
    }).toList();
    return Order(
      itemId: parsedData['itemId'],
      itemName: parsedData['itemName'],
      itemImage: imageList ,
    );
  }
```

Is this really the necessary step? since im pretty sure the list contain only String, or am i doing it the wrong way? thankyou

Answer (score 0):

In your original factory fromMap you need to cast it to a list of string like this:

```
(parsedData['imageList'] as List).cast<String>()
```